# How would you differentiate between UI (User Interface) and UX (User Experience) testing?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

I have a project, where we need to test both the UI and UX, and that needs to happen in separate. 
How do I implement the UX part of this? UI for one thing, can be tested using Selenium, but UX part is tricky, because it depends on the User perspective.

One of the suggestions I have found in our team discussions, is to have UX scenarios, built in during the Usability Testing of the application. How does this suggestion sound? I am open to any more ideas.

I have searched SQA SO, but apart from [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13462/what-are-the-similarities-and-differences-between-ux-as-a-software-quality-and-o), nothing seems to be substantial in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All answers properly describe the distinction between UI and UX testing. But how to **test UX**?

Popular method to test differences between two designs is [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing). But to get statistically significant results, you need to test on big samples  (hundreds or thousands) of users (randomly assigning design A to one set of users, and design B to the rest, and measuring differences of whatever you want to improve).

Other that that, UX is validated by heuristics and "rules of thumb of good UX design", like [10 Usability Heuristics for User Interface Design](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/) and [Top 10 Mistakes in Web Design](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-mistakes-web-design/). Jakob Nielsen website is treasure trove of UX ideas, he does UX for living for 20+ years.

Comment: A/B Testing was another option suggested. I don't have much idea on this topic. I will explore it. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 2):

See as per my knowledge I will say that both differs to each other many respects but yes they are often either miss-considered or one of them is not considered at all (and that is UX testing).

**UI testing** is more related to **GUI testing** (Graphical User Interface) i.e. the overall look and feel of the application. It put stress on the appeal of the application like the positioning of the fields, Color of the buttons, tabs. In my opinion this testing is quite important because this is the thing which differentiates between Homemade food and Restaurant food, because there all the dishes are well dressed and served. Also, from user perspective (human perspective) first thing which catches mind attention are the looks of the application and when you get a new release (lets say after 6 months) and you find UI to be updated/changed then definitely it gives a impression that something has changed in the application (especially the end users).

Also, the senior people of the organization (who got a product developed) pay more attention to this UI testing as they need it to be in sync with other products and company Logo and its color etc. I have worked for a client where even 1 pixel of UI distortion was not considered good as they use to pay more (or equal) attention to both UI and functionality. This testing becomes more tedious when you have to test multiple browsers (because sometimes designer have to design browser level CSS).

**Now coming to UX** i.e. User Experience testing. In our Organization this kind of testing is done by a separate team (known as **SAU**: **Security Accessibility and Usability testing)** and very often we include QAs from other projects (we don't include our team QAs for this testing). This testing includes Overall experience of the User with application (User can compare it with other standard applications too, if he/she wants). It includes Accessibility and Usability of the application for different types and different minds of users.

E.g. User here tests that for creating a new record he need to make 5 extra clicks which can be saved, How easy and user friendly is the application is for him/her as a user? So, it can be done manually with Users enriched with such knowledge. That's why I mentioned earlier that we don't include our regular QAs in this testing, because by the time we reach to this stage of testing they already had a mind set that application works in this way, hence they were not able to find UX issues.

UX testing is often neglected or not considered during the delivery of projects for many reasons.

Comment: Precisely. I have seen it neglected in many projects I have worked with.

Comment: I think what you have said was mentioned by my team as well, to include the UX scenarios in Usability testing part. We don't know as of now, if any other team will be conducting this tests or we would do it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

UI testing is about testing the mechanical aspects of the UI, e.g. "Does filling out this form and clicking this button do what's expected?"  You can automate parts of UI testing.

UX testing is about measuring how human beings interact with your UI, e.g. whether they are confused by the UI, or it frustrates them, or (in a bigger sense) lets them accomplish whatever they have been led to believe it will do.  I don't know how to automate UX testing.  Ideally, this happens with people who fit your user profile and who do not know you or care what you think, i.e. not the developer sitting next to you or your manager or the marketing person down the hall.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding, in simplest terms:

UI testing - does the User Interface work as intended?
UX  testing - is the intended User Interface even good in the first place?

UI testing is the job of QA (make sure all the buttons work, verify expected behaviors, etc.)

UX testing is for a separate team entirely. A UI can have no defects or bugs, but it might still be a horrible user interface in terms of usability, and that's where UX comes in.